# How to modify response (get) function in angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to move this function to services.js:

```
News.all().async().then(function(data) {
  $scope.news = data['data']['NewsList'];
});
```

And than call it in controller.js by this command:

```
$scope.news = News.all();
```

I try many ways, but them did not work.

Here is my services.js:

```
.factory('News', function($http) {
  function returnNews() {
    return {
      async: function() {
        return $http.get('test.json');
      }
    };
  }
  return {
    all: function() {
      return returnNews();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you call `News.all()` in the end you will get an object with an async property: `{async}` and I don't think this is what you want. What you can do is pass a callback to the service:

```
.factory('News', function($http) {
  return {
    all: function(callback) {
      return $http.get('test.json').then(callback);
    }
  }
});
```

and in the controller you have to do:

```
News.all(function(data){
  $scope.news = data
});
```

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern. Instead of converting a promise into a traditional callback-style async operation, just expose the promise and chain to it. `News.all().then(function (data) ...` and have News.all return `$http.get('test.json')`

Comment: Yes, or you can do as @WilliamB sugested